# Kickstart Price slider in front page

Tags: commerce, search

Can any one say that how will i show my `kickstart` price slider in front.

I read many reference but still at no where . I use the `multiblock` module but the block produced is only shows in the search page.

Then I also try through view . I create another `facet block` using `facet api` but there is no option for changing the display widget.

is there any way or i am missing something .

Any help is most appreciable . thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it myself 
i create a facet block with price field and a search block of index type which will show the facet in every where the search page will shown .i restricted it for only front page .Then it works for me.